# Downgrade MySQL 8.0.34 to 8.0.28

Tags: apt, 22.04, mysql

We recently migrated from CentOS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and have 3rd party software (AlphaCard ID Suite) which no longer connects to MySQL after moving to version 8.0.34. The vendor is telling us that others have reported the same issue for MySQL versions after 8.0.28 and asked us to downgrade to 8.0.28.

Before starting, I looked at apt-cache policy which showed the following:

[image]

So I backed up the databases and followed [this procedure](https://geniusgeeks.com/uninstall-mysql-ubuntu/) to completely remove MySQL. Once I was sure it was gone, I ran the install for 8.0.28 using this command:

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-server=8.0.28-0ubuntu4
```

After the install was complete, version still showed 8.0.34.

[image]

Did I miss a step?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `mysql -V` is going to return the client version, rather than the server version - I think?

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, but mysqld -V returned the same result

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is explicitly itemizing all 3 server packages and all 3 client packages:

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-server=8.0.28-0ubuntu4 mysql-server-8.0=8.0.28-0ubuntu4 mysql-client=8.0.28-0ubuntu4 mysql-client-8.0=8.0.28-0ubuntu4 mysql-server-core-8.0=8.0.28-0ubuntu4  mysql-client-core-8.0=8.0.28-0ubuntu4
```

After that, I used apt-mark hold to prevent upgrades to these packages:

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold mysql-client
$ sudo apt-mark hold mysql-client-8.0
$ sudo apt-mark hold mysql-client-core-8.0
$ sudo apt-mark hold mysql-server
$ sudo apt-mark hold mysql-server-8.0
$ sudo apt-mark hold mysql-server-core-8.0
```

Everything appears to be at the version I need now.